# grep command to find 2 patterns separated by X or less characters

Tags: regex, grep

I am looking for a command using egrep that can find all files, in a folder, containing two specific patterns (the first pattern is `tata` and the second is `tutu`), separated by a "maximum distance" (measure in a number of characters, say 50 or less of any character). Something like this would possibly be close:

```
egrep -ri "tata[.]*tutu" /folder/
```

but I don't know how to limit the number of characters between the two string patterns I am interested in.

Comment: Can these words appear on different lines or same line?

Comment: The brackets around the dot in your attempt changes it from the regex "any character" to a literal dot (a character class containing this character and nothing else). To match repeated arbitrary characters, the regex is `.*` (dot star, where the star means zero or more repetitions of the preceding expression).

Comment: Dear anubhava, the words may appear on 2 different lines. Dear tripleee, you're right, initially, I had [A-Za-z '-]*, but I thought it would be easier with the '.' and I didn't realize it would need to be without []. So that would make it egrep -ri "tata.*tutu" /folder/. But how do I change zero or more repetitions to 50 or less for instance?

Comment: Why `-i`? Should `tAtA` also be matched?

Comment: Dear Benjamin W, yes it should be case insensitive; so the -i command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
egrep -ri "tata.{,50}tutu" /folder/
```

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards):

> {m, n} ... Matches the preceding element at least m and not more than n times. For example, a{3,5} matches only "aaa", "aaaa", and "aaaaa". This is not found in a few older instances of regexps. BRE mode requires {m,n}.

So `{,50}` means 50 times or less the given pattern

Comment: Dear Entimon, this works fine. Although I need it to work across multiple lines. So I added the option -z to suppress new line at the end of line and it seems to work fine. So that makes it egrep -riz "tata.{,50}tutu" it can probably be improved. thanks all